# My PC’s display is showing green as grey

Tags: display

My display randomly started showing green as grey today and it won’t stop.

I’ve tried to go into my settings and my advance display settings to see if I can change it but nothing works.

Like when I'm playing the SIMS its so off-putting and unenjoyable because the grass is just grim and dull and grey.

Comment: Have you tried removing and re-inserting the video cable?

Answer (score 0):

Check if green based colors, like yellow, are displayed properly or not.

If yes then probably problem can be with card or cable. In this case remove cable clean it then replug it.

For video card uninstall and reinstall the driver using device manager (assuming you have discrete graphic card).

Or else, if yellow is not properly displayed then probably green diode have been blown up. For this change your monitor.